# popup using javascript not showing properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, popup

I've been through 2 web-related classes with similar projects in popup using html and javascript, but the problem is that the popup either won't show at all or showing for half a second and immediately closing on itself. I can't post the whole code, but here's the rough block of code (I put the script at the very bottom of the file, outside the html tag):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
 var btn = document.getElementById('btn_popup');
 var close = document.getElementById('close');

 btn.onclick = function(){
  popup.style.display = "block";
 }
 close.onclick = function(){
  popup.style.display = "none";
 }
</script>
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="titleBar">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div>
   <form action="page.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="item"> by 
    <select name="search">
     <option value="v1">Value 1</option>
     <option value="v2">Value 2</option>
     <option value="v3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
    <button id="btn_popup">Popup Button</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="popup">
  <div id="popup_content">
   <header>
    <span id="close">X</span>
    <p>Popup Form</p><br>
   </header>
   <article>
    <div>
     <form method="POST" action="page.php">
      <input type="text" name="n1" placeholder="N1">
      <input type="text" name="n2" placeholder="N2">
      <input type="text" name="n3" placeholder="N3">
      <input type="text" name="n4" placeholder="N4"><br>
      <select name="list">
       <option value="">Select One</option>
       <?php
        //code to generate options
       ?>
      </select><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Click">
     </form>
    </div>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I copied these parts of code from other pages, but they no longer work on this page but they work on the previous page without any problems. I also use PHP to generate the dropdown list in the popup form. In the previous page, the popup shows like it should be, but in this page the popup only shows for like half a second and closes by itself.

Is there any fix to this? Or at least any clues on the problem? And please don't recommend me to use framework (other than w3, but not w3 modals) to fix this. I'm using the latest Google Chrome to view these files, already tried with Mozilla as well but gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">
```

causes a load of page.php when you click the button.

The reason for this is that the default "type" of a button tag is "submit".

Just add type="button":

```
<button type="button" id="btn_popup">Popup Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the problem is that the popup either won't show at all or showing for half a second and immediately closing on itself.

This is because the form is getting submitted once u clicked on popup button.

Keep your popup button outside of the form, otherwise you have to handle prevent events.

```
<form>
  //your code
</form>
<button id="btn_popup">Popup Button</button>
```

I created a fiddle, please check it once

https://jsfiddle.net/ponrajpaul/42g9bk3c/